# Android intent filter not working just after install

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

My application registers an intent filter to open a type of file used for sharing data between users, which is working fine, with one exception, as mentioned below.

After the application has been installed, and the import file is clicked on in a browser application (e.g. the DropBox Android application), the application does not appear in the "complete action using" dialog the first time. If the import is tried again, however, it works - and every time after that.  Also, if the application is opened at least once after installing, and before trying to import files, it also works.

It might be worth noting that the application opens immediately, without going via the "complete action using" dialog, and without setting the application as a default, when it works.

This does come up quite frequently with users, because they often install the application and then immediately try to import some of the sample files, so the app starts with some content.

How can I ensure that the application will receive intents immediately after install?

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="za.ac.sun.battlemanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="za.ac.sun.battlemanager" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <provider
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.datatransfer.CachedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.gmailattach.provider" >
        </provider>

        <!-- linkage for the test runner -->
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.ScenarioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.StartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.StartActivity" />

            <intent-filter>

                <!--
                     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.LoadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_load"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.ExportActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_export"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.ExportScenarioListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_export_scenario_list"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.ExportLibraryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_export_library"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.ExportScenarioActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_export_scenario"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.ImportActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:mimeType="text/xml"
                    android:pathPattern=".*.war" />
                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/xml"
                    android:pathPattern=".*.war" />
                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                    android:pathPattern=".*.war" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateCharacterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_character"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateItemActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_item"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateTerrainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_terrain"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditTerrainListActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateZoneActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_zone"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditCharacterListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_character_list"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditItemListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_item_list"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditTerrainListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_terrain_list"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditZoneListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_zone_list"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditPowerListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_effect_list"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreatePowerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_effect"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditPowerListActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditEffectListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.EditConditionListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_condition_list"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateConditionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_condition"
            android:parentActivityName="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="za.ac.sun.battlemanager.CreateActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right one `android:mimeType` and `android:pathPattern` in the same `<data>` tag. Also there should only be one `<data>` in one `<intent-filter>`. My suggestion: split into six separate `<intent-filter>`.

Mind you, even if you did there is also my problem [How did intent-filter change from Android 2 to Android 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650378/how-did-intent-filter-change-from-android-2-to-android-4)